# How to update MasterViewController item cell from DetailViewController

Tags: uitableview, detailview

I'm trying to update the items in a UITableViewCell connected to my root view table via a UIButton in my detail view.  The item cell is imported into the root view, loaded and registered in viewDidLoad, updated in viewDidAppear, and added to the table in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender
{
//saves new list
RoomItem *item = [[RoomItem alloc] initWithRoom:[_roomTxt text] Building:[_buildingTxt text]];
[[RoomList sharedStore] createItem:item];

//allows for immediate return to rootView upon action (save button push in this case)
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Even though Xcode predicts "createItem", I get a warning that "No visible @interface for 'RoomList' declares the selector 'createItem:'

**I've imported RoomList.h, where:**

```
- (RoomItem *)createItem;
+ (RoomList *)sharedStore;
```

**In RoomList.m:**

```
- (RoomItem *)createItem
{
//tracks what number item it's creating
double order;
if ([allItems count] == 0) {
    order = 1.0;
}
else
{
    order = [[[allItems lastObject] objectIndex] doubleValue] + 1.0;
}
NSLog(@"Adding after %d items, order = %.2f", [allItems count], order);
RoomItem *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoomItem"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
[p setRoom:[NSString string]];  //there was an order call here
[p setBuilding:[NSString string]];
[p setBuildingThumbnail:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString string]]];    //may need to be changed to another imageNamed function
[p setBuildingThumbnailData:[NSData data]];
[p setObjectIndex:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:order]];
[allItems addObject:p];

return p;
}
+ (RoomList *)sharedStore
{
static RoomList *sharedStore = nil;
if (!sharedStore) {
    sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
}
return sharedStore;
}
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
return [self sharedStore];
}
```

**In RoomItem I have:**

```
- (id)initWithRoom:(NSString *)room Building:(NSString *)building;
```

I just can't wrap my head around what I could be missing here.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

**Edit (root view method that writes to item cell):**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore defaultStore] allItems]
                                objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
//[[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];

//get the new or recycled cell
HomepwnerItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomepwnerItemCell"];

[cell setController:self];
[cell setTableView:tableView];

//configure the cell with the BNRItem
[[cell nameLabel] setText:[p itemName]];
[[cell serialNumberLabel] setText:[p serialNumber]];
[[cell valueLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", [p valueInDollars]]];

[[cell thumbnailView] setImage:[p thumbnail]];

return cell;
}
```

This is what worked for me. It seems I was not properly fetching the core data entity. However, the objectAtIndex query is still an issue since it only updates the RoomItem at index:0. How can a get the index of the RoomItem I'm trying to update?

```
- (RoomItem *)updateItemWithRoom:(NSString *)room Building:(NSString *)building
{
NSError *error = nil;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RoomItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

RoomItem *currentRoomItem = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
request = nil;

[currentRoomItem setRoom:room];
[currentRoomItem setBuilding:building];

[self saveChanges];

return currentRoomItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title is about master/detail view controller communication. But a compiler warning seems to be at the heart of your question.

It's a matter of method signatures.

```
[[RoomList sharedStore] createItem:item];
```

This calls method signature is `-createItem:`. You declare `-(RoomItem *)createItem;` or `-createItem`. Note there's no colon, no passed in parameter.

It seems unlikely that you would pass a `RoomItem` in to a method named `createItem` so you likely want to just change the above call to:

```
RoomItem *item = [[RoomList sharedStore] createItem];
// item is now the newly created entity.
```

**Or** change the `createItem` method to something like:

```
-(RoomItem *)createItemWithRoom:(NSString *)room andBuilding:(NSString *)building{
    // Use room & building to create managed object
}
```

And then use it like:

```
RoomItem *item = [[RoomList sharedStore] createItemWithRoom:[_roomTxt text] andBuilding:[_buildingTxt text]];
```

**EDIT**

If you're trying to refresh the master tableview in the detail view of a split view controller (on iPad) you can use code like this to reload the master tableview.

```
UINavigationController *masterController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
UITableViewController *tableController = (UITableViewController *)masterController.visibleViewController;
UITableView *tableView = tableController.tableView;
[tableView reloadData];
```

On the iPhone/iPod you can obtain the navigation controllers root view controller and refresh the table view with code like this.(written a bit more compactly)

```
UITableViewController *masterTableViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[masterTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

Of course instead of a full reload you could use a method like `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` if you know the future `indexPath(s)` at the time of insertion.

Comment: Your correct, the title should reflect the compiler error.  

createItem is a RoomList method, and should be writing an instance of RoomItem to the data model entity RoomItem.  From here, the root view should be able to grab each attribute and pass them to the cell.  I've placed the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method where this happens to the original post.

Comment: Will this still work if I'm using a data model to CRUD?  The RoomList file is being used by the detailViewController to call and update these attributes (room, building).

Comment: What I need is to pass the initWithRoom[_roomTxt text] Building[_buildingTxt text] method in the detail view controller to the createItem method in RoomList.  How do I extract the room string in the former, and place it in [p setRoom:NSString] withing the later?

Comment: Okay, got it working.  You were right about changing the createItem method.  I made it - (RoomItem *)createItemWithRoom(NSString *)room andBuilding(NSString *)building.  In the DetailViewController:addItem is wrote [[RoomList sharedStore] createItemWithRoom:[_roomTxt text] andBuilding[_buildingTxt text]];  and [self.navigationController reloadInputViews]; and it works!  I just need to create another IBAction within the detail view that updates the cell rather than creating a new one.

Comment: See update above for partially resolved code. I'm still having an issue with querrying the RoomItem currently being edited (found at objectAtIndex:0)

Comment: Ultimately, what I need is to fetch the objectIndex of the RoomItem being edited and pass it to updateRoomItem.  Is there a way of doing this in the DetailViewController?